# Изменения цвета текста в XML разметке (android, strings)

Tags: android, xml, aide

[image: хмл файл]

Как изменить цвет текста в стрингах? Пробовал тег < font > - не сработало: при компиляции программы та часть текста, к котой применил тег стала прозрачной.
Может у xml свои теги? Хотя например тот же < b > работает..

Comment: Как вариант можно строку полностью описать в html а затем добавлять в TextView с помощью fromHtml

Comment: Это как? Расскажите? / upd: разобрался

Comment: В этом файле я определил тект в html https://github.com/StanleyProjects/BullsCows_alpha/blob/master/res/values-ru/strings.xml а в этом файле я его применяю к TextView https://github.com/StanleyProjects/BullsCows_alpha/blob/master/java/stan/bulls/cows/ui/activities/RulesActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Вот как пример для красного цвета:

```
 <string name="hello_worldRed"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#FF0000>Hello world!</font></b>]]></string>
```

Для синего

```
<string name="hello_worldBlue"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#0000FF>Hello world!</font></b>]]></string>
```

Ну и соответственно все в гугле есть вот [тут](http://ohandroid.com/strings-xml-2.html)

```
<string name="hint_of_create_account"> <font fgcolor="red">Hello</font></string>
```

Вот еще пример

```
<string name="hint_of_create_account"> <font color="#5b2828">Hello</font></string>
```

Проверил на android studio, там это работает

Comment: Не помогло. Текст "покрылся" тегами. Т.е они встали вокруг него обычным текстом

Comment: @МаркусСтельмах Добавил еще один способ, но он ограничен малой цветовой палитрой

Comment: @МаркусСтельмах Вот два последний варианта рабочие, но я тестировал в android studio